# Spring + Angular BasicAuth problem with 401 http error

Tags: angular, spring

Here is my angular code

```
public authenticate(username: string, password: string) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    Authorization: 'Basic' + btoa(username + ':' + password)
  });
  return this.httpClient.get<User2>("http://localhost:8080/login/book", { headers: headers })
    .pipe(
      map(
        userData => {
          sessionStorage.setItem('username', username);
          return userData;
        }
      )
    );
}
```

Here is simple authenticate method in Spring

```
@GetMapping("/login/book")
public User2 authentication() {
  return new User2("User authenticated");
}
```

Comment: Probably needs a space after `Basic` in the auth header. There should be a space between the word *Basic* and the "token".

Comment: Where does this `username` variable come from (js)? How is this `authentication()` method supposed to work (spring) - post your SecurityConfig?